# Vue call sibling's method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<root>
   <my-button @click="save()"/>
   <my-form/>
</root>
```

---

```
my-form.vue

methods:{
   save(){}
}
```

How to call **save()** from **my-form** via **my-button**?

Comment: Emit and listen to events, or use Vuex. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Answer (score 2):

You can use an event bus:

```
let EventBus = new Vue();

let MyButton= Vue.extend({
    name: "my-button",
  props: ["what"],
  template: `
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-success the-button" @click="save()">Sender: {{what}}</button>
  `,
  methods: {
    save: function(){
        EventBus.$emit("form.save", //pass payload here);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("my-button", MyButton);

***my-form.vue:****

 created(){
     EventBus.$on('form.save', (payload)=>{
         this.save(payload)
    });
},
methods:{
    save(payload) {}
}
```

Full working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/arvidkahl/gxdn6ycv/17/

Comment: whether siblings are also have parent child relationship?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as you use the same EventBus, they all listen to the same events